# How to Select-All in Terminator

Tags: shortcut-keys, terminator

How can I select all the text in a Terminator terminal? Ctrl-Shift-A does not work.

Comment: try to use [Screen](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935)

Comment: So, it seems this feature is still missing. Has anyone requested for it to be added to the next version of Terminator?

Answer (score 66):

I don't have the menu bar, nor the option to show it. So I have this workaround:

1. Shift + Home
2. Select the first line
3. Shift + End
4. Shift + click on the last character

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I would have never figured out the `shift + click` part. Thanks you!

Comment: This works for the regular terminal as well as with Terminator !!

Comment: The neat thing is that after clicking the first character or line you can drag the scroll bar with your mouse, it doesn't reset the selection. So even if there's a million lines you can still select and copy all of them quickly. And you can select from the bottom to the top, not jut top to bottom.

Answer (score 30):

The quickest way to select all / select specific text in Gnome Terminator:

1. Click at the start of the text you want to select
2. Scroll the window to the end of the text you want select
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click the end of your selection
4. All text between your first click and your last <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click is now selected
5. Then you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> your selection out of there

It's not a keyboard shortcut, but it's a lot faster than click-and-drag to select text, that's for sure.

Answer (score 14):

Your select all is disabled by default.

1. Go to Menu->Preferences->Shortcuts
2. From **Edit** selection choose "Select All"
3. Then to assign press Ctrl+Shift+A

Comment: I am surprised built-in solution doesn't get more recognition. It works for me in Gnome Terminal 3.36.2 (in Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS). Is this a recent addition to Gnome Terminal?

Comment: To do this, with my default settings (U21.04, 3.38.1):

2. In Edit selection, _doubleclick_ "Select All". Singleclick just hangs there

Comment: @Joe Kul Press the keys. Simulate. Process number #3 above.

Comment: This only copies one screenful of the output, not all of it. Not a solution at all.

Comment: @Violet-Giraffe This procedure is used to "enable" the select all command, ie. Control+shift+a . So follow the above procedure to "ENABLE" the "DISABLED" command.

Comment: @BiddutMitra: as I said, that command is useless, it's actually "select screen", not "Select ALL"

Comment: @Violet-Giraffe  Iain Samuel McLean Elder said very well indeed. LOL.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same goal and modified [Thierry Ds copyall-Terminator-Plugin](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1059675/comments/1) to be just a [select-all](https://github.com/egroeper/terminator-plugins/blob/master/selectall.py).

Install and activation:

- copy selectall.py into /usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/plugins/
- restart terminator to discover the new plugin
- in terminator:

  - right-click->Preferences
  - switch to Plugins tab
  - select SelectAll
  - click Close

Now you can Select-All by:
right-click->Select all

Perhaps I should add a shortcut as well.

Comment: Is there a way to attach a keyboard shortcut to plugin actions? Struggling to find documentation

Comment: From what I've seen at first sight, I don't think that is currently possible.

Comment: @EnnoGröper You have mixed tabs and spaces in `selectall.py`. Specifically, before `terminal.vte.select_all()` line you have a tab instead of spaces.

Comment: @previous_developer Thanks for the hint. Fixed it.

Comment: Groping for a long time, finally this solved :good:

Answer (score 4):

No Shortcut, use Mouse: click on Menu -> Select All

Only true for Program: Terminal

Comment: There is no Menu Bar in my Terminator window.  In the Context/Right-Click Menu only Copy and Paste is available

Comment: It seems it is not implemented: https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1091960

Comment: As bmm wrote, there is no menu bar in Terminator.

Answer (score 4):

1. Right click at terminal
2. In menu check: Show menubar
3. In the menubar: Edit->Select All
4. Right click at terminal: Copy

Comment: This process copies ONLY current "terminal" page.

Comment: Well, this worked for my in any text content. Thanks Eugen

Answer (score 1):

(This depends on terminal/distro - what worked for me with huge output):

start selecting with mouse and then press PgUp/PgDn

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.1.0 needs this settings changed.

[image]