# Can I search in the terminal backlog in Terminator

Tags: search, terminator

I'm using Terminator as my terminal. Is there a built-in way to find/search through the output backlog? I'm not looking for `grep` and piping a command, or piping into `less` or `vim`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Terminator has a built-in search (ctrl-shift-f is the default keybinding), but it doesn't highlight the found text, which makes it fairly useless.

There's a bug open against terminator to fix this, but right now it's still unresolved:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator/+bug/271487

Comment: You just made this account to answer this question, right? Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Happy to help. :-) I'm really hoping the terminator devs will be able to get this one fixed soon. It's a great program.

Comment: Just started using terminator today.. I already ran into this and hope for the same. For ppl wanting this feature: go to the launchpad page, register, and click "This bug affects me" at the top of that page.. Though I don't hold great hopes, as that feature request is almost 10years old now.. :(

Comment: Stumbled upon this thread today: bug has status fix committed, so things are moving forward. Milestone: Terminator 2.1.

Comment: Man, I wish I always knew this. I can't tell you how many times I've [copy and pasted](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126741/256054) from Terminator to a text editor just to find something. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You can install latest version on ubuntu where the bug is solved

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mattrose/terminator
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install terminator
```

See https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Answer (score 7):

This actually has been resolved for `terminator 2.1`, yes good things do happen in 2020. However it's not on the repo yet, but you can clone the
[github terminator repo](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator)

And follow the steps form [install guide](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/blob/master/INSTALL.md)

Basically it will take you to

```bsh
git clone git@github.com:gnome-terminator/terminator.git

sudo apt-get install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-psutil python3-configobj \ 
                gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gettext intltool dbus-x11

# In the folder where you've cloned the repo
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record=install-files.txt
```

you should be able to spawn a terminal from that point by running from the folder where you've cloned the repo

```bsh
python3 terminator
```

And have the desired search working