# How to get Enno Gröper selectyall-Terminator-Plugin working (Ubuntu)?

Tags: python, plugins, terminator, copy-and-paste

I am working on Ubuntu running inside a VM made from Virtualbox on Windows 10.

By looking for a way to select all the text in a Terminator terminal, I get to following [this AU thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1145271/1342430) , indicating how to install [**Thierry Ds copyall-Terminator-Plugin**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1059675/comments/1).

The **copyall.py** plugin was modified and transformed by Enno Gröper into a **selectall.py** plugin, available [here on Github](https://github.com/egroeper/terminator-plugins).

I tried to redo the steps mentioned in the AU thread, but I can't get my plugin working:

From my terminator:

```
cd /usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/

sudo mkdir plugins

cd plugins

sudo vim selectall.py
```

I paste in there the code from https://github.com/egroeper/terminator-plugins/blob/master/selectall.py

Exit and save and check that the text is effectively saved in there

Restart Terminator

Right click on Terminator > preferences > plugin

But the new plugin is not there.

How can I get it appear and work?

--- UPDATE ---

To give you some more context, I am pasting here:

1. the output of `ls -al /usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/plugins/`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rd5w.png)

2. a screen capture of Right click on Terminator -> Preferences -> Plugins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeLpj.png)

3. a screen capture of what I see (in particular, the context menu) with Right click on Terminator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvS78.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I made the plugin work by pasting the `selectall.py` file into this path:

```
/home/<my_user_name>/.config/terminator/plugins
```

Note: I had to create the last folder of the path, `plugins`.

However, the plugin looks quite useless because it copies only the text shown in the "current screen" of Terminator, and not the entire text that you can see by scrolling the Terminator window.

I'm disappointed.

Comment: This works only for your user. It may be good enough for your uses.
You may try my solution in less than 2 minutes, to check if that works globally.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your plugins folder is somewhere else.
Please post the output of (copy-paste as text, not screen capture):

```
$ locate /maven.py
$ locate /custom_commands.py
$ locate /url_handlers.py
```

and if it is something different, try adding `selectall.py` in that directory.

Comment: sorry, I misreported my folder path: it's `.../plugins/` and not `.../plugins/plugins`. I updated the question.

Comment: @Tms91 - So please post in the OP:
1) the output of `ls -al /usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/plugins/`,
2) a screen capture of *Right click on Terminator* -> *Preferences* -> *Plugins*,
3) a screen capture of what you see (in particular, the context menu) with *Right click on Terminator*; if you cannot screen-capture, use your phone to take a picture.

Comment: Done, question updated. Thanks for your answer

Comment: solved, i m writing the answer to close the OP. thaks 4 your time

Comment: @Tms91 - See EDITed answer.